LLM Function calling in Spring AI results in error : exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type
I tried to implement function calling with Spring-AI but I see that method parameters are not passed correctly.
For example I have this function 'routeChatFunction' that takes AgentChatRequest as input class.
I am calling LLM in this way in service layer. User query is coming from controller layer.
           chatClient.prompt()
                .system(SYSTEM_PROMPT)
                .user(userQuery)
                .functions(getAgentInfoFunction(), routeChatFunction())
                .advisors(a -> a
                            .param(CHAT_MEMORY_CONVERSATION_ID_KEY, conversationId)
                            .param(CHAT_MEMORY_RETRIEVE_SIZE_KEY, 100))
                .toolContext(Map.of(
                    "chatId", conversationId,
                    "userQuery", userQuery
                ))
                .call()
                .content();
    



 private FunctionCallback routeChatFunction() {
    return FunctionCallback.builder()
            .description("This function helps route the user query chat to a specific agent and helps generate the response.")
            .function("routeChat", (request, context) -> {
                log.info("request: {}", request);
                String chatId = (String) context.getContext().get("chatId");
                String userQuery = (String) context.getContext().get("userQuery");
                log.info("Using chat ID: {}", chatId);
                return this.chat(
                    ((AgentChatRequest)request).getAgentId(),
                    chatId,
                    userQuery
                );
            })
            .inputType(AgentChatRequest.class)
            .build();
}


@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonClassDescription("This is the request object for the agent chat. It contains the agentUUID, chatId, and the user query. It takes the agentUUID as input. Make sure to pass the agentUUID as the input.") 
public class AgentChatRequest {
    private UUID agentId;
 
}

But when I run this code, even though LLM has information of AgentUUID through getAgentInfoFunction(), it doesn't pass the same to routeChatFunction(). It sends some random UUID and resulting in following error

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type java.util.UUID from String "<UUID_of_the_agent_specialized_in_account_creation>": UUID has to be represented by standard 36-char representation
at [Source: REDACTED (StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION disabled); line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.monetize360.mpillotv2.modules.ai.dto.AgentChatRequest["agentId"])]

Can someone help with some information regarding why this happens and what is the way around to build robust solution? It works sometimes and sometime doesn't. Is it a limitation on LLM Model being used or the way I have implemented or limitation from the way spring-ai works (Unlikely??) ?
In general what is the accuracy of function calling by LLM seen in industry? Is it right most of the times?
I am using

Spring-AI 1.0.0-M4


With llama3.2 Model.


Running locally using ollama.

Any help is appreciated.

Are you using any controller to send the request?

Yes I am taking user query from controller request body and then passing down to service layer that triggers LLM call.
